# How to chose a value of a constant type based on an unrelated type?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Ok, so I got the following simplified working example before the change I want to make:

```
data D = D
data C = C

class T a where
  t :: a

instance T D where
  t = D

instance T C where
  t = C

g :: T a => IO a
g = do
  return t

main = (g :: IO D) >> return ()
```

So the problem is that, inside `g`, I want values of types unrelated `a` to be chosen based on `a`. In other words, I want to express that if `a` is `C` then some value of yet unmentioned type `e` will be chosen and if it's not then another value of type `e` will be chosen. It's basically conditionalizing on arbitrary type equality, like pseudocode `if a ~ Bool then "foo" else "bar"`. I tried this like so (using `String` for the type `e` in this example):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
import Data.Proxy

class F sub1 sub2 where
  f :: Proxy (sub1, sub2) -> String

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} F a b where
  f _ = "did not match types"

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} F a a where
  f _ = "matched types"

data D = D
data C = C

class T a where
  t :: a

instance T D where
  t = D

instance T C where
  t = C

g :: forall a b. (T a, F b a) => IO a
g = do
  putStrLn $ f (Proxy :: Proxy (D, a))
  putStrLn $ f (Proxy :: Proxy (C, a))
  return t

main = (g :: IO D) >> return ()
```

I get the following errors, though:

```
y.hs:30:14: error:
    • Overlapping instances for F D a arising from a use of ‘f’
      Matching instances:
        instance [overlappable] F a b -- Defined at y.hs:10:31
        instance [overlapping] F a a -- Defined at y.hs:13:30
      (The choice depends on the instantiation of ‘a’
       To pick the first instance above, use IncoherentInstances
       when compiling the other instance declarations)
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘f (Proxy :: Proxy (D, a))’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn $ f (Proxy :: Proxy (D, a))
      In the expression:
        do putStrLn $ f (Proxy :: Proxy (D, a))
           putStrLn $ f (Proxy :: Proxy (C, a))
           return t
   |
30 |   putStrLn $ f (Proxy :: Proxy (D, a))
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

y.hs:31:14: error:
    • Overlapping instances for F C a arising from a use of ‘f’
      Matching instances:
        instance [overlappable] F a b -- Defined at y.hs:10:31
        instance [overlapping] F a a -- Defined at y.hs:13:30
      (The choice depends on the instantiation of ‘a’
       To pick the first instance above, use IncoherentInstances
       when compiling the other instance declarations)
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘f (Proxy :: Proxy (C, a))’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn $ f (Proxy :: Proxy (C, a))
      In the expression:
        do putStrLn $ f (Proxy :: Proxy (D, a))
           putStrLn $ f (Proxy :: Proxy (C, a))
           return t
   |
31 |   putStrLn $ f (Proxy :: Proxy (C, a))
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

y.hs:34:9: error:
    • Overlapping instances for F b0 D arising from a use of ‘g’
      Matching instances:
        instance [overlappable] F a b -- Defined at y.hs:10:31
        instance [overlapping] F a a -- Defined at y.hs:13:30
      (The choice depends on the instantiation of ‘b0’
       To pick the first instance above, use IncoherentInstances
       when compiling the other instance declarations)
    • In the first argument of ‘(>>)’, namely ‘(g :: IO D)’
      In the expression: (g :: IO D) >> return ()
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = (g :: IO D) >> return ()
   |
34 | main = (g :: IO D) >> return ()
   |         ^
```

The errors suggest `IncoherentInstances` but it doesn't seem like it would chose the correct instance. I've yet to come up with something new to try.

EDIT: Just for the sake of seeing what would happen, I activated `IncoherentInstances`, but it results in the same errors.

EDIT 2: I'll explain how the example is linked to my practical, actual scenario. `g` represents an HTML form. This form can return different types represented by `T`. These different types use different subsets of the fields in the form. The lines in `g` that have `putStrLn` and `f` represent the definitions of the fields in the form. `f` represents deciding whether or not to validate a field depending on if the form is returning a type that depends on it.

As an example, the form might return a type `DocSectionA` or `DocSectionB`. A field might be type `Text`, and we want to express that a particular field should only be validated when the form is returning a `DocSectionA`, and another field should only be validated when the form is returning a `DocSectionB`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Right, that's why I hoped using the pragmas `OVERLAPPING` and `OVERLAPPABLE` would cause the instance where they are necessarily equal to override the instance where they may or may not be.

Comment: @assembly.jc Because it varies. I may call `g` to get a `D` and other times I may call `g` to get a `C`. I get the feeling Li-yao Xia may have also misunderstood that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what your `T` class is for. It doesn't appear to actually be used in an interesting/relevant way. But your `f` can be implemented using equality checks on `TypeRep`s. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import Data.Type.Equality
import Type.Reflection

data C = C
data D = D

f :: forall a b. (Typeable a, Typeable b) => String
f = case testEquality (typeRep @a) (typeRep @b) of
    Just Refl -> "matched"
    _ -> "didn't match"

g :: forall a. Typeable a => IO ()
g = do
    putStrLn (f @C @a)
    putStrLn (f @D @a)

main = g @D
```

You can of course use proxies in the usual way to avoid ScopedTypeVariables and AllowAmbiguousTypes if that's your preferred way. I've used the new fancy-typed version of `Typeable`: although we didn't use it above, in the `"matched"` branch of `f`, not just us but also the typechecker knows that `a ~ b`.

Comment: `T` is interesting :). It's just a simplified example. I'll explain how the example is linked to my actual scenario in an edit to the question.

Comment: @JoL `T` may be interesting for you, but seems orthogonal to the question of checking type equality -- which is the part you're actually having difficulty with. So what I'm saying is that whatever you're doing with `T`, great, and it can almost certainly be mixed with the technique I've shown here without great effort.

Comment: The relevance lies in that its variable determines the instances used.

Comment: I've added an EDIT to the question explaining how the different things in my example links to my actual scenario.

Comment: I'm currently reading your example to understand if it applies. I've never used `Typeable` so I'm looking into that.

Comment: @JoL I'll be honest, none of what you describe in your edit sounds like it needs type equality checks at all. I think you should consider describing what you're trying to accomplish in more detail (in a new question) -- it sounds to me like a bog-standard parser-combinator-like approach is going to be right up your alley, and doesn't require any fancy type shenanigans.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I figured learning how to do things this way (conditionalizing on a type) would also be generally useful. Maybe later I'll post a question that's more specific to my scenario to learn of alternative ways of doing subforms. For now, would you, by chance, know of an alternative that doesn't depend on `Type.Reflection`? Turns out the project I'm working on is using `base-4.9.1.0` from stack's `lts-9.6` and `Type.Reflection` doesn't appear until `4.10.0.0`.

Comment: Got it. I just had to replace `testEquality (typeRep @a) (typeRep @b)` with `eqT @a @b`, where `eqT` is from `Data.Typeable`. This is great.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how we'd do it nowadays with ambiguous types and type applications. Ambiguous types allow you to have class members that don't mention the class parameters (otherwise you can use proxies).

Here `c` is `0` if `a ~ T`, or `1` if `a ~ U`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications #-}

data T
data U

class C a where
  c :: Int

instance C T where
  c = 0

instance C U where
  c = 1

main :: IO ()
main = print (c @T) >> print (c @U)
```

If you really want to match *any* type in the event that `a` is not `T` (why would you though), you can use overlapping instances (and the [GHC manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#overlapping-instances) is the best reference about how they work):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-} -- in addition to the above

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} C a where
  c = 0

main = print (c @String)
```

Comment: This showed me that I can avoid the use of `Proxy` by using `AllowAmbiguousTypes` and `TypeApplications`, which is great. Thank you. However, I think you misunderstood the main problem. The crux is that I have a function (represented by `g` in my example) where the definition of each line varies depending on whether a type variable in `g` matches with a concrete type that's different in each line. Using your approach, one variable is not enough to determine what definition applies. I could use 2 and instantiate only using concrete types, but it would be many instances and only 2 definitions.